# click event is not getting triggered with puppeteer API

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I m trying to test web page of my project with **JEST** & **Puppeteer** testing tool. In web page when i right click on  element one  menu pops up in page with setting some style attributes on  element. So with this flow i m trying to test the same with **JEST**, I have written following code for the same.

```
describe('Test for Rest Data', () => {
  jest.setTimeout(100000);
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await page.goto("url", { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await page.waitForSelector('table');
  });
});
test("Assert for delete row !",async () => {
  await page.click('tr','right');
  const tbl = await page.evaluate(()=>{
    return document.querySelector('tr').getAttribute('style');
  });
  expect(tbl).not.toBeNull();
});
```

here when i click on  of table style attribute gets added but with above code tbl is not getting any value.

Am I doing something wrong ? How should I do this right ?

Answer (score 0):

You should also probably wait for some time after the click, maybe the style changes but not instantly, maybe the element is not there yet.

Try,

```
await page.waitFor(1000); // wait for some time
// or this below
await page.waitFor('tr'); // wait for the element
```

Which will wait for some time or the element. Check if that is the case.

Comment: When you check visually with headless:false, does the right click actually happen? Does it show anything at all?